# String escape in SQL statement

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to do the following query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(provider) FROM raw_financials 
                WHERE vendor_id="%s" OR title='%'", (vendor_id, title))
```

My problem is that the title can be anything, for example it can be `"Hello, Sir", 'Yes' he responded`. So when I do the above, I could get a (bad) return value, such as `An Elf\\'s Story` (which raises a SQL error).

How would I correctly quote the SQL statement and the title here?

Comment: Depends on the database, some want backslashes (`A\'B`), some want doubled-quotes (`A''B`), etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't quote it yourself; your DB driver will do it for you:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(provider) FROM raw_financials 
            WHERE vendor_id = %s OR title = %s", (vendor_id, title))
```

Edit: Above, `%s` are placeholders which indicate where the arguments (`vendor_id` and `title`) should be inserted. MySQLdb uses `%s` for placeholders, but some other drivers use `?`. You may have to change my code above to use the placeholder appropriate for your driver.

Comment: Shouldn't be `?` instead of `%s`?

Comment: It depends on the driver. sqlite3 and oursql use `?`, while MySQLdb uses `%s` placeholders. Thanks for reminding me that my answer was (unwittingly) MySQLdb-specific.